Вопрос по оператору is
Подскажите почему Foo1 компилируется а Foo2 нет?
static void Foo1()
{
   int? a = 1;

   if (a is int b)
      b *= 2;
   else
      b = 3;

   b *= 10;
}

static void Foo2()
{
   int? a = 1;

   if (false) { }
   else
   if (a is int b)
      b *= 2;
   else
      b = 3;

   b *= 10; // <- Error CS0103: The name 'b' does not exist in the current context.
}


Во втором варианте добавьте {} вокруг ветки else. Тогда будет понятно.

@AlexF, да - я позже и сам догадался что "под капотом добавляется" {}. Только в данном конкретном (хотя и бессмысленном) коде не очень-то и ожидаешь это.

У вас отступы в коде неверные, поэтому кажется, что b на верхнем уровне, а не внутри родительского else.

Если написать код нормально, а не "случайно" пропустить все скобки, тогда можно и понять что и как работает. Вот аналогичный пример
public void Method()
{
    if (true)
    {
        int a = 10;
        if (a is int b)
        {
            b = 10; // Ok
        }
        b = 20; // Ok
    }
    b = 30; // Error
}

Условны, мы можем сказать, что когда мы используем конструкцию if (a is int b), переменная b остаётся в области видимости на уровне оператора if. В вашем первом случае, так и происходит:
static void Foo1()
{
    int? a = 1;

    if (a is int b)
    {
        b *= 2; // Ok
    }
    else
    {
        b = 3; // Ok
    }

    b *= 10; // Ok
}

Но во втором случае, вы не можете вынести переменную b за область видимости верхнего if. Если написать код нормально, всё сразу станет на свои места:
static void Foo2()
{
    int? a = 1;

    if (false)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        if (a is int b)
        {
            b *= 2; // Ok
        }
        else
        {
            b = 3; // Ok
        }
    }

    b *= 10; // <- Error CS0103: The name 'b' does not exist in the current context.
}


   if (false) 
   { 
   }
   else
       if (a is int b)
          b *= 2;
       else
          b = 3;
       // здесь переменная b ещё существует

   // а здесь уже нет

   b *= 10; // <- Error CS0103: The name 'b' does not exist in the current context.


Логично, а почему же первый метод компилируется?
